# Reading a csv file by column

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have a code to read csv file by row

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
        print(row[0])
```

But i want only selected columns what is the technique could anyone give me a script?

Comment: When you say you want only selected rows, do you mean you want to completely skip reading (from disk?) the columns you're not interested in, or you just want to filter out the columns you aren't interested in?

Comment: want to read only the column i am interested in

Comment: Is the CSV data fixed-width? I think that's the only way what you are asking is possible, and even then it might not make much sense unless you have many very wide (in terms of data) columns. Why do you think you need to skip reading these columns?

Comment: Also, it's extremely rude to ask for us to "give you a script"; StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, but a "we help you to help yourself" platform.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    column_one = [row[0] for row in readCSV ]
```

Will give you list of values from the first column. That being said - you'll have to read the entire file anyway.

Comment: wow, I admire your politeness. If I'm asked by someone who's not showing an attempt at solving something to "give me a script", I kind of get upset. Have my upvote!

Comment: Well, while I prefer to see some attempts too - we all have started from something and sometimes it's just a question without any understanding of how it can be done. Reference can be a good start. (There are a lot of those over the net besides SO though :D)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because files are written byte-by-byte to your filesystem. To know where one line ends, you will have to read all the line to detect the presence of a line-break character. There's no way around this in a CSV.

So you'll have to read all the file -- but you can choose which parts of each row you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for that.

However, in plain python this one of the way to do it.

In this example I am extracting the content of row 3, column 4.

```
import csv

target_row = 3
target_col = 4

with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    n = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row == target_row:
            data = row.split()[target_col]
            break

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` in `pandas` module can load a subset of `columns`. 
Assume you only want to load `columns` `1` and `3` in your `.csv` file.

```
import pandas as pd

usecols = [1, 3]
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv',usecols=usecols, sep=',')
```

Here is [Doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for read_csv.
In addition, if your file is big, you can read the file piece by piece by specifying `chucksize` in `read_csv`